# Manjaro Linux - Cable unplugged even if plugged

Tags: networkcard

I have just installed the system (Manjaro) and I have one, major, problem: it says that my network cable is unplugged, even if it's plugged.

I have a Realtek RTL-8110SC/8169SC Gigabit Ethernet and with Windows it works with no problem.

If I do ***ifconfig*** in the terminal, I get:

```
enp7s1: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
    ether 14:da:e9:21:fd:bf  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
    RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
    inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
    inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
    loop  txqueuelen 0  (Local Loopback)
    RX packets 384  bytes 30176 (29.4 KiB)
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 384  bytes 30176 (29.4 KiB)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

The "enp7s1" should be my card (I recognise the MAC), but usually isn't it "eth **X**" ?

Also, here is the output for ***lsmod*** command:

```
Module                  Size  Used by
rfcomm                 51153  4 
fuse                   74541  3 
raid1                  27772  1 
bnep                   11037  2 
usblp                  12722  0 
bluetooth             308366  10 bnep,rfcomm
rfkill                 15666  3 bluetooth
iTCO_wdt                5407  0 
iTCO_vendor_support     1929  1 iTCO_wdt
mxm_wmi                 1467  0 
evdev                   9880  5 
joydev                  9663  0 
hid_generic             1153  0 
md_mod                105782  1 raid1
coretemp                6038  0 
kvm_intel             128977  0 
kvm                   376330  1 kvm_intel
snd_hda_codec_hdmi     29733  1 
microcode              13172  0 
psmouse                85132  0 
serio_raw               5041  0 
snd_hda_codec_realtek    35645  1 
r8169                  57640  0
lpc_ich                12849  0 
mii                     4027  1 r8169
i2c_i801               11237  0 
snd_hda_intel          35309  5 
snd_hda_codec         147506  3 snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel
snd_hwdep               6332  1 snd_hda_codec
snd_pcm                77765  3 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_intel
snd_page_alloc          7202  2 snd_pcm,snd_hda_intel
snd_timer              18718  1 snd_pcm
snd                    58950  17 snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_hwdep,snd_timer,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_pcm,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_intel
acpi_cpufreq           10502  0 
soundcore               5418  1 snd
mperf                   1203  1 acpi_cpufreq
i7core_edac            17669  0 
edac_core              44137  2 i7core_edac
asus_atk0110           12000  0 
wmi                     8283  1 mxm_wmi
processor              27755  1 acpi_cpufreq
button                  4669  0 
nfs                   145074  0 
lockd                  76805  1 nfs
sunrpc                221055  2 nfs,lockd
fscache                44575  1 nfs
ext4                  456475  1 
crc16                   1359  2 ext4,bluetooth
mbcache                 5866  1 ext4
jbd2                   81946  1 ext4
hid_logitech_dj        10567  0 
usbhid                 41466  0 
hid                    88502  3 hid_generic,usbhid,hid_logitech_dj
sr_mod                 14898  0 
sd_mod                 30730  4 
cdrom                  34848  1 sr_mod
ata_generic             3370  0 
pata_acpi               3387  0 
crc32c_intel           14185  0 
firewire_ohci          31837  0 
firewire_core          51955  1 firewire_ohci
ahci                   22792  5 
uhci_hcd               24531  0 
ehci_pci                4120  0 
libahci                21169  1 ahci
crc_itu_t               1363  1 firewire_core
xhci_hcd               89423  0 
ehci_hcd               47672  1 ehci_pci
libata                171016  4 ahci,pata_acpi,libahci,ata_generic
usbcore               177151  6 usblp,uhci_hcd,ehci_hcd,ehci_pci,usbhid,xhci_hcd
scsi_mod              127772  3 libata,sd_mod,sr_mod
usb_common              1648  1 usbcore
radeon                807573  2 
i2c_algo_bit            5391  1 radeon
drm_kms_helper         35438  1 radeon
ttm                    65324  1 radeon
drm                   231136  4 ttm,drm_kms_helper,radeon
i2c_core               23720  5 drm,i2c_i801,drm_kms_helper,i2c_algo_bit,radeon
```

I already tried to change the interface from "down" to "up", but it remains down without displaying any errors.

I have the kernel  3.10.1-1-MANJARO (linux310)

How can I solve this?

P.S: Excuse me for my english, of course.

Comment: The `ifconfig` output shows `UP`, have you tried configuring an IP address for it? Where are you seeing that it says the cable is unplugged? What is the output of `ethtool enp7s1`?

Comment: A new network naming scheme was introduced with [systemd 197 at the start of this year](http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/PredictableNetworkInterfaceNames/). Your interface is enp7s1. You can change it back if it really matters to you, using a udev rule.

Comment: @Patrick I already tried to assign an ip, but no luck. The ethtool says that the device has 10 Mb, Half-duplex stuff (I am on windows right now).

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
sudo ethtool -s enp7s1 speed 100 duplex full autoneg on
```

I had the same problem, this worked for a couple of times, now it doesn't, I'm still not really sure why.

Comment: This seems more like a comment than an answer.

Comment: Yes, i just can't comment.